# Google cloud store - monitoring changes to files

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I want to monitor my GCS buckets for files being uploaded. Seems like **StackDriver** is the place for this but I don't see any metrics that apply.

Is this even possible? Can I run a java service that gets notifications when files are added to a bucket? AWS can do this (via SNS/SQS) but I haven't found a GCS equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Object Change Notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) feature to get notified of changes to your bucket.